# Change fncychap language and "Chapter"

Tags: sectioning, expex, fncychap

When I create a chapter heading using `fncychap`, it writes the word "chapter" in Hebrew (פרק), which makes sense given that Hebrew is the default language in this file.

1. How can I change it to say something in English instead of Hebrew?
2. How can I change it to say something
   other than "Chapter" (e.g., "Story" instead of "Chapter")?

**MWE (xetex):**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{FrankRuehl}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup

\lingset{
    everygla=\Large,
    everyglb=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    everyglc=\scriptsize\englishfont,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
   }

\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand{\swapboxes}[2]% #1 = wide text, #2 = narrow text
{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\checkoddpage
 \ifoddpageoroneside
   \parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}\hfill\parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}%
 \else
   \parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}\hfill\parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}%
 \fi}}% this \swapboxes macro forces the parboxes to switch sides every odd page

\begin{document}
\chapter{title}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa //

\endgl \xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא בב גגגג דדד אאאא בבבבב גג דדדד אא בבבב גגגגג דדד אאאא בבבב גגגג דדדד אא בב גג דד אאאא //

  \glb aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa  //

  \glc aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa bbb ggg ddd aaaa //

\endgl \xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize\textenglish{Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is some non lipsum text to fill up this space Here is the end} \xe}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I feel like @UlrikeFischer might be able to help.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Redefine the \@chapapp-Command:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Ezra SIL} %changed font
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap} %Options: Sonny, Lenny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup

\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@chapapp{Chapter}% or whatever
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like it to say "Chapter 1" instead of "1 Chapter".

Comment: Any idea how to switch "Chapter" and "1"? This is the crux of the problem that I can't figure out.